# container exited when docker run command

Tags: docker

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:8.1.0
RUN http-server
RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 2000
```

build the image successfully

```
docker run -d -p 8101:2000 --name xyz image
```

Container created and exited.
When running `docker logs container_id`, nothing displays.

This is the process that I am following but unable to know the reason why my container is getting exited.

Comment: It is running default entrypoint, and when entrypoint has completed its work, the container exits.

Comment: okay, got it, can you share me the reference where this is present?

Comment: I am trying to find the specific version from [library/node](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/)

Comment: okay, I understood the concept behind this.

Comment: you can write the answer so that I can close the question.

Comment: Although this concept is solved, but going forward I changed my docker run command by placing the --entrypoint flag and running the command , I got my container as `up`, as I have mapped my ports to `-p 8101:3000` and opend the security groups for port 8101 on ec2 instance, and fetching the app `ip:8101` but the site is not reached.How can I know where the problem is?

Comment: You should see logs to find if there were any errors while accessing the site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151858/discussion-between-aditya-and-ayushya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is running default entrypoint, and when entrypoint has completed its work, the container exits.

If you want to edit the entrypoint, then either you specify your own or see what the default entrypoint is doing. You may find the dockerfile ans entrypoint details of your specific version in [library/node](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/)

Answer (score 0):

The Docker container runs as long as the process started with the CMD command inside the docker file is still running.

In your case, you didn't specify a CMD command in your docker file, and thus your container will exit immediately.

I can see that you intend to run an http-server. In that case, remove `RUN http-server` and replace it with `CMD http-server` in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ping google.com` as a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` to enable continuous process of a container. There are scenarios that you really need to let that container still run even though it's process should end quickly. Example is when your cron is not yet ready for automated scraping